# Extracting a string with regular expressions that contains a certain word anywhere in the string

Tags: python, regex, extract, brackets, curly-braces

I am having difficulty understanding regex syntax for this specific issue I am facing. I am using Python.

Here is a sample output (with random values) of sensors I am using that is in a txt file:

```
Sensors starting
{'device_id': 'M123'}
{'x_acc': 0.00, 'y_acc' : 0.01, 'z_acc' : 1.02}
```

But from another device I am getting it like this:

```
Sensors starting
{'device_id': 'S123'}
{'y_acc': 0.00, 'z_acc' : 0.01, 'x_acc' : 1.02}
```

What I want to do is extract anything between { and } with, let's say, 'x_acc' in it so it detects both strings and doesn't select the line with the device ID as it gets printed multiple times in the same file every few minutes.

I was able to come up with this pattern:

```
pattern = r'\{.*?\}'
```

To select the lines with { } but I want to specify the lines with x_acc, y_acc, or z_acc in them to be chosen. I was able to do it when I knew the first item - then I added it to the pattern, but since the order changes from one device to another, I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
{[^{}]*'[xyz]_acc'[^{}]*}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1U4FeT/2).

*Details*:

- `{` - a `{` char
- `[^{}]*` - zero or more chars other than curly braces
- `'[xyz]_acc'` - a `'` char, then a `x`, `y` or `z` char, and then a `_acc'` substring
- `[^{}]*` - zero or more chars other than curly braces
- `}` - a `}` char.